# Hash Sum mismatch in ubuntu 16.04.3

Tags: python, c++, ubuntu, gcc

```
makinsane@makinsane:~$ sudo apt install python-pip && sudo apt install python3-pip

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  build-essential cpp-5 dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-5 gcc-5 gcc-5-base
  libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl
  libasan2 libatomic1 libcc1-0 libcilkrts5 libexpat1-dev libfakeroot
  libgcc-5-dev libgomp1 libitm1 liblsan0 libmpx0 libpython-all-dev
  libpython-dev libpython2.7-dev libquadmath0 libstdc++-5-dev libstdc++6
  libtsan0 libubsan0 python-all python-all-dev python-dev python-pip-whl
  python-pkg-resources python-setuptools python-wheel python2.7-dev

Fetched 37.6 MB in 2min 4s (303 kB/s)                                          
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-5/cpp-5_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
```

Comment: the last error. hash sum mismatch for gcc-5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `sudo apt clean && sudo apt update` first.

Comment: If that doesn't help, search for answers at https://askubuntu.com/. Which is probably where this question belongs as well.

Comment: it worked thank you

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens if the data was corrupted during HTTP transfer or on the mirror.  Try putting a different mirror int `/etc/apt/sources.list` (or any other file your system uses for mirror configuration) and retry.

Comment: how do i do that?